# How can I unload an SWF that is already loaded to my file on actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to make a system that is first unloading any existing (loaded) flash SWF's and then loading one back in (so they won't overlap each other).

I am using a class AS3 file
My code looks like

```
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
        removeChild(myLoader);
        myLoader.unload();
        var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("URL HERE");
        myLoader.load(url);
        addChild(myLoader);
```

As you can see I'm trying to unload everything first, and then load the new stuff, for some reason it's not working.

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

This line creates a new `Loader` object.

```
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
```

It's pointless to call `unload()` on that object, because there's no way anything could be loaded.

What you should do instead is to work with a single `Loader` object. Do not create new one every time.

Comment: You ought to mark this answer as correct. Mark the green tick by the answer.